# Enum namespace not available

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, syntax

I've got this code running since some time without error. Today, a new error occurs. Perhaps after Windows Update?

> Error  1   'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Integer)'.   C:\myclass.vb   3274    35  TBDevice
>   .

```
Dim value As String = "00000001"
Dim B() As Byte = Global.System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, value.Length / 8).Select(Function(pos) Convert.ToByte(value.Substring(pos * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray()
```

any idea how to get rid of the bug?

Comment: You are missing an import from you file: `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: No. Import of System.Linq is done. The error does not write that the namespace is not found. It says something about Integer type. I don't understand.

Comment: Look in the rest of your code for a method you named "Select".

Comment: I see "selected". but there is no kind of integer. Perhaps its because of the syntax I don't understand but I have no idea how to fix that row of code! Any idea?

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I just did what nemesv said. Imported the whole namespace instead of typing it in front of the function. ** now it works **. Please, can you post it as answer because its not me that answered this question.

Comment: As nemesv probably missed your comment, I did it for him (as CW, so no rep involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an import from you file: `Imports System.Linq`.